# iOS - another thread needs to send reloadData to the mainthread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, uiview, reloaddata

I got a separate thread that creates a UIView object, inserts it into the UITableView's data source and then call reloadData on the UITableView. However, since it is a separate thread, it cannot call reloadData directly, it needs to make the mainthread do it... but how do you tell the mainthread to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                 withObject:nil
                              waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I came here to copy this line :) . Tq

Answer (score 7):

You can use dispatch async, this method allows you to marshal worker thread to blocks of in-line code rather than methods using performSelectorOnMainThread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
});'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? (may not compile, I am typing it out)

```
- (void) callReloadData
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        @synchronized (self.tableView) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: `performSelectorOnMainThread:` will invoke its selector immediately if `waitUntilDone:` is YES, so this code pointless.  (I have no idea why you chose to throw in a `@synchronized` block either.)