# Do I need to use @synchronized when calling UITableView reloadData method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have many threads calling UITableView's reloadData method concurrently. Do I actually have to put a @synchronized block around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't call reloadData from threads other than the main thread.

See this similar question:

[iOS - another thread needs to send reloadData to the mainthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914299/ios-another-thread-needs-to-send-reloaddata-to-the-mainthread)

Answer (score 5):

`reloadData`, like any other method on a view, should **only be called from the main thread only**. So you don't need `@synchronized` because only one thread should be there at a time.

If you're on a background thread and you want the table view to reload, use `dispatch_async` to make sure the reload happens on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myTableView reloadData];
});
```